# Programmable Thermostat wiring Question

Tags: hvac, thermostat

Existing thermostat is a Honeywell and has a separate  connections  for Aux (*white  wire*) and E (*Emergency black wire*)
The proposed Honeywell T'stat only has  a single terminal labeled  "Aux E".

How do I connect  this?

Choices are  several:

1. Secure  the Black wire  and  connect  the  white  wire only?
2. Secure the white wire  and  connect  the black wire only?
3. connect both  wires parallel at the Aux E terminal?

Comment: A picture of any diagrams would be helpful.

Comment: What model is your new thermostat? Can you post photos of the wiring at the air-handler/furnace for your system?

Comment: Don't treat this lightly.  Emergency heat is serious business.  It typically costs 4 times as much to run it. The thermostat should be programmed to only use e-heat when primary heat is absolutely unavailable e.g. due to low temperatures.   If you play casual with the connections here, you could find your electric bill jumping $300 in the winter.